# How can I resize pane in byobu in iTerm2 using keyshorts M-S-Up/Down/Left/Right?

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux, iterm2, byobu

I use byobu+tmux in iTerm2, I found that keyshorts for resizing panes is M-S-Up/Down/Left/Right but when I press then I just got character typed like this:

[image]

Comment: Don't know on Mac but on ubuntu it is Alt+Shift+Arrows, maybe that helps someone

Comment: You can use the ubuntu shortcuts in OS X/iTerm 2, but you have to apply some key remapping as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180096/os-x-byobu-vertical-split

Comment: @licavero Yes!  Alt-Shift+Arrows works great in iTerm2 on OSX.  Confirmed.

Answer (score -2):

Should be `alt`-`shift` + arrow keys.